# Set my initial bounds to represent India (location) in Geomajas application

Tags: geomajas

I am new to Geomajas. I followed document and configured my shapefiles as a vector layer on top of Google Maps.

Can any one tell me how can I set my initial map bounds to represent India location in Geomajas application.

Comment: have you set the initialbounds like shown here: http://files.geomajas.org/maven/trunk/geomajas/docbook-devuserguide/html/master.html#conf-map

Answer (score 1):

in the map configuration (ClientMapInfo) you can define initial bounds like this:

```
<property name="initialBounds">
            <bean class="org.geomajas.geometry.Bbox">
                <property name="x" value="-1000000"/>
                <property name="y" value="5000000"/>
                <property name="width" value="4000000"/>
                <property name="height" value="2000000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

The bounds should be defined in your map coördinate system.

Additionally you can configure the viewboundslimitoption, whether the initial view must lie completely within the maximum bounds, or it must center in the maximum bounds.

These are the two options, just try both and have a look what suits you best:

```
<property name="viewBoundsLimitOption">
<value type="org.geomajas.configuration.client.BoundsLimitOption">CENTER_WITHIN_MAX_BOUNDS</value>
</property>
```

OR

```
<property name="viewBoundsLimitOption">
<value type="org.geomajas.configuration.client.BoundsLimitOption">COMPLETELY_WITHIN_MAX_BOUNDS</value>
</property>
```

Hope this helps!